# How to use an instance of a class in an another class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**Login.java**

```
public class Login_Details {
    public static WebDriver dr;
    public void verifyLogin() throws Exception {
        dr= new FirefoxDriver();
        dr.get("http://www.nexterp.in:9992/NextERPQA/nerp/login");
        FileInputStream fi= new FileInputStream("C:\\NexterpProject\\Next_Testdata\\src\\Testdata.xls");
        Workbook wb= Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
        Sheet s= wb.getSheet(0);
        dr.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys(s.getCell(0,1).getContents());
        dr.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(s.getCell(1,1).getContents());
        dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Thank you for Logging in");
    }
```

and
**Logout.java**

```
public class Logout{
public static WebDriver dr;

public void comesOut() throws Exception{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a[2]")).click();
    System.out.println("Thank you for clicking on Logout");
    dr.quit();
    }
}
```

in the above two programs there am creating an instance for **webdriver** dr;
my question is instead of creating every time a new instance for new class, tell me how can i use that **dr** in my programs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move initialization of static object from method to variable declaration E.g.

```
 public static WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
```

And then reuse it every where like

```
Login_Details.dr
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the driver during initialization phase.

```
public static WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **extend the "Login.java" class in "Logout.java"** like below, (and also do **import the Login class in Logout class too**):

`public class Logout extends Login`

Then you can directly use `dr` in **"Logout.java"**

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseClass which contains driver initialization with driver as static. Extend BaseClass to each and every class and reuse driver object.

```
public class BaseClass{
    static WebDriver driver;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

in Login_Details

```
public class Login_Details extends BaseClass{
    public void verifyLogin() throws Exception {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.nexterp.in:9992/NextERPQA/nerp/login");
        <your code>
    }
}
```

and in Logout.java

```
public class Logout extends BaseClass{
    public void comesOut() throws Exception{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body...")).click();
        <your code>
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to make your driver static, its better you follow PageObject design pattern. Using that u can provide your code without extending BaseClass.

in Login_Details

```
public class Login_Details{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    public Logout verifyLogin() throws Exception {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.nexterp.in:9992/NextERPQA/nerp/login");
        <your code>
        return new Logout(driver);
    }
}
```

and in Logout.java

```
public class Logout{
    WebDriver driver;
    public Logout(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void comesOut() throws Exception{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body...")).click();
        <your code>
    }
}
```

So your test method would look like:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    Login login = new Login();
    Logout logout = login.doLogin();
    logout.doLogout();
}
```